# I can't dig certain materials in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been playing the game for a little while already, and this hasn't happened until now. Suddenly, I can't dig certain blocks like sand, dirt, gravel, cobblestone, bookshelves, and cacti. I can, however, dig through leaves with a sword equipped. Any suggestions?

Comment: Log and relog???

Comment: You may be in adventure mode, somehow? Did you mess with your /gamemode at all?

Comment: Not sure about the dupe. Are there any other blocks you can't break? Can you place blocks?

Comment: The sword on leaves is a dead giveaway: you are in adventure mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have changed your gamemode to adventure. Adventure mode is used to play adventure maps (you can only break blocks with specific tools.)

To fix press esc. press open to LAN, choose enable cheats. Open the lan world. now press t (to open op chat) and type in: `/gamemode 0` this will set your gamemode to survival, and should fix it.

Comment: good that i could help ;D. mark this answer as helpfull if it helped